# Parse: PFQuery performed locally or remote

Tags: parse-platform

I'm quite new at Parse.
When making a query by PFQuery is the query performed on the Parese servers and only the resulting objects sent back to the phone? 
Or is it that all possible objects are transferred to the phone and the query performed locally?

As I understand it is performed remotely at the Parse servers, right?
Many thanks for a short YES or NO

Comment: what does logic suggest? Would you want a million rows returned when you only need 3?

Answer (score 0):

You are only every returned objects that are matched with your query, and the default settings are to run queries remotely.

However, you can also fetch cached results if you've run a query before so the request doesn't need to go out to Parse.com and will return data to you much quicker. The default cache settings are to query via the network only, so every query you run will go to Parse.com and come back with the results. If you alter the query cache policy for your query, the device may use results that are cached on the device so you don't need to go to the network again.

This applies (at least) for the iOS SDK. I'm not sure what the other SDK's do.